# How do I create a feature request?

Tags: trello

I can see the development board and vote for ideas, but I cannot seem to create a new idea/feature request.

In this questions tool I've seen responses that say NOT to put feature requests into Questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can submit feature requests to `feature-ideas@trello.com`